# why does this code produces output like this but not like this?

Tags: python

when I give these inputs to list:

```
List: 123 234 543 2 22 9
min = 123, max = 9
```

it returns 123 as min and 9 as a max number where as it should be 543 as max and 2 as min

```
while True:
    input_string = input("List: ")
    if not input_string:
            exit()
    ListArray = input_string.split()
    max_value = max(ListArray)
    min_value = min(ListArray)
    print("min = {}, max = {}" .format(min_value, max_value))
```

I expect the output to be 543 as max and 2 as min

Comment: You need to convert the string to a number.

Comment: Note that `ListArray` should instead be named `list_array` to comply with [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (Python's code-style conventions), which specifies CapWords (aka CamelCase) only for class names, not for other variables.

Answer (score 1):

Each value in Python is of a particular data type - for example, string, number, list, dictionary, objects (of various kinds), etc. They have different semantics. Let's try this:

```
>>> "abc" + "def"
'abcdef'
>>> 1000 + 999
1999
```

When you split the string input by the user into items, those items remain strings. For strings, `"a" < "aa" < "b"`, and similarly `"1" < "11" < "2"` (see [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)).

To find the maximum and minimum *numbers* in the list, you have to convert all the individual strings:

```
ListArray = [int(s) for s in ListArray]
```

Note that if the input had anything but numbers, the program will now raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of jhpratt's comment, one way that you can do this is through a list comprehension. You can change the line `ListArray = input_string.split()` to `ListArray = [int(i) for i in input_string.split()]`, which will cast each of the elements in `input_string.split()` into an int.

If you would rather use a `for` loop instead of a list comprehension, you can do this:

```py
for i in range(len(ListArray)):
    ListArray[i] = int(ListArray[i])
```

This should make your code do what you expect it to!

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the `input_string` entered by the user, use list comprehension to cast each string element of `input_string.split()` into an int. At this point `ListArray` is basically a list of numbers and you can now easily calculate the minimum and maximum value.

```
input_string = input("Insert a list of numbers: ")
ListArray = [int(i) for i in input_string.split()]
print("min = {}, max = {}" .format(min(ListArray), max(ListArray)))
```

Comment: Because this doesn't explain *why* the old code is wrong and the new code is right, it's not as helpful as it could be in assisting the OP in not making the same mistake again in the future.